# How do you embed addtional RSS feeds into the <head> section of your theme

Tags: 7, theming, feeds

I have 5 RSS feeds I am looking to embed into the `<head>` section of the page. What is the best way to accomplish this on drupal 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `drupal_add_feed()` or if you don't want to have an icon appear
on the page itself

```
 drupal_add_html_head_link(array(
    'rel' => 'alternate',
    'type' => 'application/rss+xml',
    'title' => $title,
    'href' => $url
  ));
```